# Order Results By Row Valuation Calculation Answer

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query providing me with a table full of the correct descriptions and figures:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_sale_basket WHERE ORDER_ID=$ID");

$total=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $quantity = $row['QUANTITY'];
  $description = $row['NAME'];
  $unitprice = $row['PRICE'];
  $lineprice = $row['PRICE']*$row['QUANTITY'];
  $total=$total+$lineprice;

$tbl_header = '<table style="width: 650px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';
$tbl = '';

$tbl .= '
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($quantity,0).'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 350px; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.$description.'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 125px; text-align:right; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($unitprice,2).'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 125px; text-align:right; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;" align="right" ><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($lineprice,2).'</p></td>
    </tr>
';
```

As you will be able to see the $lineprice is calculated by:

```
$lineprice = $row['PRICE']*$row['QUANTITY'];
```

Now I would like to order the table results based on the value in this field.  I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM b_sale_basket WHERE ORDER_ID=$ID ORDER BY '$lineprice' ASC
```

But that doesn't work.  How could I order the results in the table by this column?

Thank you in advance,
Andy

Comment: `ORDER BY` expects a column name, not a value contained in the column.

Comment: Understood, so is there anyway of ordering by this figure?

Comment: See Marc B's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORDER BY PRICE * QUANTITY
```

Ordering by a fixed number, like you're trying won't work, because the DB will have NO idea what field(s) to compare that fixed value against. But if you do the multiplication within the deb, as in the above snippet, you'll get your expected sort order.

Comment: Perfect! I can't believe I didn't try this initially but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT quantity * price as total FROM b_sale_basket ORDER BY total;
```